# Why do I get "Insufficient memory for image" although there should be enough RAM?

Tags: qgis, raster

QGIS reports "Insufficient memory for image 1403x716", when I want to load a raster. The problem begins after 1 hour of work.

Had somebody had such problem?

System  win7 64 bit, 16GB RAM, Intel Core i5.

Comment: How much RAM does your machine have?  What is the size and format of the raster file?  I load up 16000x16000 size rasters all the time.

Comment: 16gb RAM. I think it not in a raster a problem. Maybe windows 7 doesn't give them to load? The problem begins, when QGIS takes away 1,5 GB from RAM.

Comment: How about your graphics card?

Comment: Nvidia GeForce GT740

Comment: Are you running 32bit QGIS?

Comment: Yes, QGIS 32bit

Comment: It doesn't matter how much RAM you have, 32 bit applications can only use 2GB RAM unless they are compiled large address aware (LAA), then they can use up to 4GB. Use the 64bit version of QGIS.